# Real symmmetric positive definite matices have all diagonal entries positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If a real symmmetric matrix $ A $ is positive definite. Is it true that all diagonal entries are positive?

I have only prove it for a matrix of order 2. How can I prove or disprove it, please give me only hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: What happens when you evaluate the quadratic form defined by the matrix at a vector with a single non-zero entry?

Comment: many many thanks.how fast did you crack so fast.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: which two vectors $v_i$ stand out in $\mathbb{R^2}$, and what happens if you calculate
$${v_i}^t A v_i?$$